# Use conference abbreviation as a bullet point + grouping

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Essentially I'm making a list of publications and I want to use a conference abbreviations as bullet points. Here is an example:

```
ACE'16   A bib ref

FSE'15   A bib ref

ACE'15   A bib ref
         An another bib ref from the same conf
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: Is your question only about how to obtained an itemized list with acronyms instead of bullets, or do you want to have some kind of automatism?

Comment: Would that be your bibliography? Or do you want that additionally to the bibliography? Where does the conference abbreviation come from? How do you currently get your bibliography? An [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) with a few example entries as well as a more detailed description of the status quo and the desiderata would certainly be helpful.

Comment: If all the abbreviations are the same length, you could use a description environment.  You could make them all the same length using \makebox[length][l].  If you don't want to make the abbreviation in boldface, you could do it using \leftskip and \llap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of setting up a list of abbreviations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]% #1 = abbreviation
{\smallskip\par\noindent\llap{\makebox[\leftskip][l]{#1}}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\leftskip}{MMM'02\hspace{\itemsep}}% longest abbreviation
\myitem{ACE'16} some text here.% \cite?
\myitem{FSE'15} \lipsum[1-2]
\leftskip=0pt% end of indentation

\end{document}
```